# Facebook / 8 Ball Pool

Tags: facebook

I got to a really high level in 8 ball pool on my iPad, I used to sign in using my Facebook account but my Facebook account recently got hacked and I’m now locked out of my Facebook account.

I sign into 8 ball pool using my newly created Facebook account but I have to start all over again in 8 ball pool is there a way I can get back my 8 ball pool data by signing in with my new Facebook account?

Best wishes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is appears to be a problem only with Facebook®, and nothing to do with iOS or Apple in any way.

Comment: Let’s leave it up. It might be an iOS app with federated log in

Comment: Close this question? Seriously .. it’s the game that keeps the saved game data not Facebook, I was just wondering if there’s a way to transfer to saved game data over to the new Facebook account.

Comment: does the iPad not simply take the login information for the game from keychain? After login data is verified is there any test/check to see wether login credentials are _still_ valid? What prevents using the old login name and password?